# Have a ViewController behind/revealed when an animation is done

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, animation

In my app, I would like to have a door, and the user swipes the door, I would like an animation to show the door opening up, and behind the opening door is a visible viewController. How could I go about doing this? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacked up two views and link UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the top view which will act as the door, and when user swipes, just do normal UIView animation to move top view to a position. (if it's a sliding door. otherwise, do some transformation or else..)